# PHP mysql_connect with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i'm creating a website with PHP. I have the information of MySQL in a file and I use `$cnf=file("cnf.txt");` to get the information. The I use `$ligacao=mysql_connect($cnf[0],$cnf[1],$cnf[2]);`. But when i enter in the website it gives me an warning in mysql_connect. But if I make an echo of the positions of the array it haves the correct values.

Can any one tell me what is wrong?

The original code:

`$cnf=file("cnf.txt");
$erro=0;
$ligacao=mysql_connect($cnf[0],$cnf[1],$cnf[2]);`

Comment: What MySQL error/warning do you receive?

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, and you should be putting your efforts into mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using the `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

The issue is probably that each value in the `$cnf` array has a trailing newline `\n` character on it from the file.

At the very least, try:

```
$cnf = file("cnf.txt");
$erro = 0;
$ligacao = mysql_connect(rtrim($cnf[0]),rtrim($cnf[1]),rtrim($cnf[2]));
```

Comment: No problem. Just always remember that when you use the `file()` function, each entry in the array will have the trailing newline so typically you will always need/want to `trim()` any values resulting from the use of `file()`.